# Component to inject and interpret String with HTML code into JSF page

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, escaping

I'm using PrimeFaces with JSF 2.0 to build one application. I'm using PrimeFaces `<p:editor>` component to enable user to create rich text. But the output of this component is HTML source which look like this:

```
String text = "<p>This text <i>contains</i> some <b>HTML</b> code.</p>";
```

When I show this in a `<h:outputText>` as below:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" />
```

Then it shows the HTML code as plain text:

> <p>This text <i>contains</i> some <b>HTML</b> code.</p>

Is there any component which can interpret the HTML source so that e.g. `<i>` is actually shown as italics and `<b>` as bold?

> This text *contains* some **HTML** code.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

JSF by default escapes HTML from backing bean properties in order to prevent XSS attack holes. To disable this, just set the `escape` attribute of the `<h:outputText>` to `false`.

```
<h:outputText ... escape="false" />
```

This way the HTML won't be escaped and will thus be interpreted by the webbrowser.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, beware of XSS attacks as you're here basically redisplaying user-controlled input unescaped. You might want to sanitize it beforehand.

- [What is the general concept behind XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233015/what-is-the-general-concept-behind-xss/)
- [CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf/)
- [Server side HTML sanitizer/cleanup for JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167104/html-sanitizer-for-jsf)
- [Escape everything but linebreaks in h:outputText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543857/escape-everything-but-linebreaks-in-houtputtext/)