# JSF's outputText escape attribute doesn't work well with <code>

Tags: java, html, jsf, jsf-2, xhtml

I have a code block like this in JSF

```html
<div class="textile">
    <h:outputText escape="false"
        value="#{NotificationContentWFHelper.generateContent(notification)}"/>
</div>
```

The string generated in value tag comes from database stored as `CLOB` which was created in Java.

I want a particular part in this string to be shown as table in the output like below.

```
Item 1081 has become the new reference item.

1081              1200              12000             0                 10                1081              
1073              1000              10000             0                 10                1073              
1069              800               8000              0                 10                1069              
1079              0                 0                 0                 0                 1079              
1074              0                 0                 0                 0                 1074
```

Each row in table is created using format

```java
String.format("%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s", rowValues);
```

As the output in our application doesn't use monospace fonts, I couldn't show it as table. So I tried using the `<code>` tag only for the tabular part. The tag was parsed but it skipped all the spaces showing

```
Item 1081 has become the new reference item.

1081 1200 12000 0 10 1081
1073 1000 10000 0 10 1073
1069 800 8000 0 10 1069
1079 0 0 0 0 1079
1074 0 0 0 0 1074
```

I further tried `builder.toString().replace(' ', NON_BREAKING_SPACE);` where `final char NON_BREAKING_SPACE = ' ';` but got this

```
Item 1081 has become the new reference item.

1081&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;1200&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;12000&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;10&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;1081&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
1073&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;1000&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;10000&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;10&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;1073&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
1069&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;800&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;8000&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;10&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;1069&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
1079&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;1079&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
1074&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;0&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;1074&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
```

Using any other tag apart from `<code>` doesn't parse like HTML. I tried using `<samp>`, `<p>`, `<table>` (with `<tr>` & `<td>`). It comes up as

```
Item 1081 has become the new reference item.

<samp>1081              1200              12000             0                 10                1081              
1073              1000              10000             0                 10                1073              
1069              800               8000              0                 10                1069              
1079              0                 0                 0                 0                 1079              
1074              0                 0                 0                 0                 1074              
</samp>
```

What am I missing here?

**Note**: I cannot change the XHTML code as this a very specific case where I need table. I do not want to disturb other things or put extra overhead on other 99 stuff for this 1 in 100. Any other approach by modifying java code could be suitable if it renders the desired output.

**Update**: As per [Component to inject and interpret String with HTML code into JSF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662851/component-to-inject-and-interpret-string-with-html-code-into-jsf-page) html should be parsed as escape is false, but it does not work in my case.

Comment: Just generate a [html table](http://divtable.com/generator/).

Comment: @krokodilko its not possible to use the link as I need to genrate the table dynamically in the code and use it for JSF output